# Kotlin Conflicting declarations: val sinAngle: Float, val sinAngle: Float

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class and function:

```
data class SinCosAngle(val sa: Float, val ca: Float)

fun angleCalc(rad: Float): SinCosAngle {
    return SinCosAngle(sin(rad), cos(rad))
}
```

I want to use the function multiple times like:

```
for (i in 0..72) {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(i * 5f - 90f)) // 1
    (...)
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
}
paint.strokeWidth = 3f
for (i in 0..8) {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(i * 45f - 90f)) // 2
    (...)
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
}

val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f)) // 3
(...)

val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f - angleArrow)) // 4
(...)

val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f + angleArrow)) // 5
(...)
```

I got errors only at lines 3,4,5. Lines 1 and 2 are OK.

```
Conflicting declarations: val sinAngle: Float, val sinAngle: Float
```

I can fix errors by changing the variable names at lines 3 and 4 but line 5 can remain unchanged.

Working code:

```
for (i in 0..72) {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(i * 5f - 90f))
    x1 = x + cosAngle * radius
    y1 = y + sinAngle * radius
    x2 = x + cosAngle * radiusShort
    y2 = y + sinAngle * radiusShort
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
}
paint.strokeWidth = 3f
for (i in 0..8) {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(i * 45f - 90f))
    x1 = x + cosAngle * radius
    y1 = y + sinAngle * radius
    x2 = x + cosAngle * radiusShort
    y2 = y + sinAngle * radiusShort
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
}
(...)
paint.strokeWidth = 2f
paint.color = getColor(R.color.red)
val (sinAngle1, cosAngle1) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f))
x2 = x + cosAngle1 * radiusCourse
y2 = y + sinAngle1 * radiusCourse
canvas.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2, paint)
x1 = x + cosAngle1 * radius
y1 = y + sinAngle1 * radius
canvas.drawCircle(x1, y1, smallCircleRadius, paint)
val (sinAngle2, cosAngle2) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f - angleArrow))
x1 = x2 - cosAngle2 * radiusArrow
y1 = y2 - sinAngle2 * radiusArrow
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f + angleArrow))
x1 = x2 - cosAngle * radiusArrow
y1 = y2 - sinAngle * radiusArrow
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
```

How to propertly use the same val name in this case ?

(Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3 October 1, 2021)

EDIT / SOLUTION
Thank you for all answers. I ended up with simple solution:

```
var sc: SinCosAngle
```

With that I can use angleCalc function without limits and extract fields with sc.sa and sc.ca

Comment: I would strongly advise to extract those identical pieces of code into functions, so you wouldn't run into conflicts for temporary variables. Then for the ones that are actual outputs, just use different names for different things ;)

Comment: *How to propertly use the same val name in this case ?* - please don't. If the variable represents different values every time, it should have a different name. This helps to make the code more readable in general. If you find that a variable plays the same role in a higher-level operation, then you should abstract this higher-level operation by extracting it into a function, so your reused variable instead becomes a local variable of that function.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to reuse the variable as a way to "optimize" anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still use the same name for the variables, you can introduce a new scope with scope functions. For example, putting each declaration in a `run` block

```
run {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f))
    // use the angles here
}
run {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f - angleArrow))
    // use the angles here
}
run {
    val (sinAngle, cosAngle) = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f + angleArrow))
    // use the angles here
}
```

I find `let` more readable:

```
angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f)).let { (sinAngle, cosAngle) ->
    // use the angles here
}

angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f - angleArrow)).let { (sinAngle, cosAngle) ->
    // use the angles here
}

angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f + angleArrow)).let { (sinAngle, cosAngle) ->
    // use the angles here
}
```

However, you cannot *reuse* the same property, unless you give up on using the destructuring syntax:

```
var angles = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f))
// use the angles here

// reusing the variable, without destructuring
angles = angleCalc(deg2rad(course - 90f - angleArrow))
```

Destructuring only works when you *declare* a property. The full name of this feature is called "[Destructuring *Declarations*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html)"

Comment: Destructuring *assignment* was requested long ago but the issue is still languishing despite many votes. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11362

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can not have two variables with same name in the same scope.

Lines 1 and 2 are working because those variable are in the scope of `for` loop. Lines 3, 4 and 5 are in the same scope that's why you can't use the same variable name in these lines.

One workaround could be to use a `var` for the radian angle (similar to how you are using `x1`, `y1` etc.):

```kotlin
var angle = deg2rad(course - 90f)
x2 = x + cos(angle) * radiusCourse
y2 = y + sin(angle) * radiusCourse
canvas.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2, paint)

angle = deg2rad(course - 90f - angleArrow)
x1 = x2 - cos(angle) * radiusArrow
y1 = y2 - sin(angle) * radiusArrow
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)

and so on...
```

This one does look a little cleaner :)

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to reuse variables instead creating new every time I use the function?

Comment: You can declare them as `var`. But then you won't be able to use the destructuring syntax.

Comment: @Artyum why do you want to do that?

Comment: I just missed the conception of 'val' scope. Thanks to everybody for explanation.